# how to add mpmath and sympy to buildozer requirements

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

Building a python program implemented in sympy for android in buildozer is still disturbing me. 
I have tried it several times specifying mpmath and sympy in the buildozer requirements, getting the same error saying:

```
"install mpmath version >=0.19".
```

how to install sympy as a buildozer requirement?

Comment: Please post the full log.

Comment: @inclement https://github.com/Ohadforman/Error-buildozer

Answer (score 1):

The `sympy` recipe is known broken and listed in the [BROKEN_RECIPES_PYTHON3 set in python-for-android](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/2b33eae5b64d3d4d91026c0326fc1e2ec58e370c/ci/constants.py#L27).

The reason seems to be a dependency ordering issue.
From https://docs.sympy.org/latest/install.html:

> SymPy does require mpmath Python library to be installed **first**

And from Ohad's build log:

```
[INFO]:    Found a single valid recipe set: ['hostpython3', 'libffi', 'mpmath', 'openssl', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'sqlite3', 'python3', 'sdl2', 'setuptools', 'sympy', 'six', 'pyjnius', 'android', 'kivy']

[INFO]:    Dist contains the following requirements as recipes: ['hostpython3', 'libffi', 'openssl', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'sqlite3', 'python3', 'sdl2', 'setuptools', 'sympy', 'six', 'pyjnius', 'android', 'kivy']
[INFO]:    Dist will also contain modules (certifi, mpmath) installed from pip

[INFO]:    Recipe build order is ['hostpython3', 'libffi', 'openssl', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'sqlite3', 'python3', 'sdl2', 'setuptools', 'sympy', 'six', 'pyjnius', 'android', 'kivy']
[INFO]:    The requirements (certifi, mpmath) were not found as recipes, they will be installed with pip.
```

So Buildozer will try to install all available recipes first, and only afterwards try to install the SymPy's mpmath dependency using pip.

One solution would probably be to add a build recipe for mpmath to make sure you build that one first: https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contribute.html#write-your-own-recipe